# javascript, dom - why do childnodes of a select are numbered every 2

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have an odd problem. I want to go through the child nodes of a select. Simple right? So this is my html:

```
    <select multiple="multiple" id="selectBoxOne" size="5" class="selectListBox">
            <option value="0" id="multiple0" {MULTIPSEL0}>0</option>
            <option value="1" id="multiple1" {MULTIPSEL1}>1</option>
            <option value="2" id="multiple2" {MULTIPSEL2}>2</option>
            <option value="3" id="multiple3" {MULTIPSEL3}>3</option>
            <option value="4" id="multiple4" {MULTIPSEL4}>4</option>
            <option value="5" id="multiple5" {MULTIPSEL5}>5</option>
    </select>
```

The thing is that dom looks like this:
[image]

So the problem is that I have that empty nodes between the real nodes. The real nodes are 1,3,5,7,9,11 instead of 1,2,3,4,5. So if I usesomething like:

```
       alert(document.getElementById('selectBoxOne').childNodes[2].innerHTML);
```

I get undefined.

I use this script in many places so I can't read only the odd numbers (since the other places are normal, without empty childs between).

Any ideea why this happened or how to fix it? Thank your for your time.

Note: {MULTIPSEL4} -> is a template variable. Is empy in this case. Is select="selected" in other cases.

Js:

```
   for (i = 1; i <= optionNumber; i++)
{
    selectOptions[i-1] = document.getElementById('selectBoxOne').childNodes[i].innerHTML;       
}
alert(selectOptions);
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have white space between the option elements. Your parser is generating a text node for each one.

Use `getElementsByTagName('option')` instead of `.childNodes` in a generic DOM or `.options` if you have an HTML aware DOM API.

Comment: Just a note: To distinguish text nodes and element nodes one can also check [Node.nodeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.nodeType). Or simply use [Element.children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Element.children) instead of `Node.childNodes`.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it the wrong way.

The correct way to iterate over drop down options is:

```
var oDDL = document.getElementById("selectBoxOne");
for (var i = 0; i < oDDL.options.length; i++) {
    var option = oDDL.options[i];
    if (option.selected) {
        alert("option with value " + option.value + " is selected");
    }
}
```

Those text nodes are there because in the HTML source you have newline and blank space characters between the `option` elements. You *can* avoid this by:

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="selectBoxOne" size="5" class="selectListBox"><option value="0" id="multiple0" {MULTIPSEL0}>0</option><option value="1" id="multiple1" {MULTIPSEL1}>1</option><option value="2" id="multiple2" {MULTIPSEL2}>2</option><option value="3" id="multiple3" {MULTIPSEL3}>3</option><option value="4" id="multiple4" {MULTIPSEL4}>4</option><option value="5" id="multiple5" {MULTIPSEL5}>5</option></select>
```

By you don't have to because you have better way to iterate the items.

Comment: What is wrong? The code cycles correctly but I have undefined for chileds 2,4,6,8,10,12. Because they should not exist. Also I already told that the code works fine for any other selects. Added javascript to see.

Comment: Why insist on using bad practice code? Anyway I added the reason what is wrong with your initial approach.

Comment: Because for some reasons .options doesn't work (it works for me but not from some colleagues and for 7 elements top it doesn't worth the while to see why). I eliminated blank spaces and is ok... still... why did it work for other pages? (had blank spaces there also.)

Comment: @zozo — No, it says that `innerHTML` is `undefined` (because text nodes don't have an `innerHTML`) not that the node is `undefined`.

Comment: You know what I wanted to say :)) Excuse my english.

Comment: `<option>` might not have `innerHTML` in some browsers, instead use `.value` or `.text` to get value or the inner text of the option element.